# asp.net core web api with angular 7 multi language support

Tags: angular, multilingual, asp.net-core-2.2

I am developing an angular 7 application with asp.net core web API. My application is multi-language supported(English and Arabic). When the user selects a language from the angular application, I am saving his language preference in local storage. Now how to send the selected language to the web API, so that based upon the selected language I can return data from the server, and display the notification in his selected language from web API.

Comment: You can send selected lang in each API header so according the data will be fetched

Comment: If you're using asp.net core web api then what is the problem that you're facing? Can you share what you have tried ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that language header **Accept-Language** is sent with each request to the server.

Since there could be many APIs and making sure that selected language header is sent with each one could be a cumbersome task, make use of **HttpInterceptor** Angular feature. Something like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class HTTPListener implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let languageRequest = req.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Accept-Language': localStorage.getItem("selectedLng") } });
    return next.handle(languageRequest).pipe(
      map(event => {
        return event;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
      }),
      finalize(() => {
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Please note that we are reading the selected language from localStorage **localStorage.getItem("selectedLng")** and passing it in the header of hte HttpRequest object.

Add the HttpInterceptor into the providers array of your root module like this

```js
providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HTTPListener, multi: true }],
```

On the ASP.NET Core side, inside the Configure method of **Startup** class,

```js
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var userLangs = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
        var lang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();

        //If no language header was provided, then default to english.
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
        {
            lang = "en";
        }

        //You could set the environment culture based on the language.
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        //you could save the language preference for later use as well.
        context.Items["SelectedLng"] = lang;
        context.Items["ClientCulture"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;


        return next();
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share asp.net core side also, how to handle the language preferences globally in .net core. Am using httpinterceptor, jwt web token in my application

Comment: Modified the answer with ASP.NET core version as well.